# How many binary bit strings of length 32 are there

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, boolean-algebra

**How many binary bit strings of length 32 are there?**

I think I know the answer but I'm not sure...wouldn't it just be $2^5$ ?

Comment: It would be $2^{32}$, since there are two choices for every bit and there are $32$ bits.

Comment: so if it asked How many binary bit strings of length 1692 are there? it would just be $2^{1692}$

Comment: yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each one of the $32$ bits can be either $0$ or $1$: So there are two options per bit.

That gives $$\underbrace {2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot \cdots \cdot 2}_{\large 32 \,\text{ factors of 2}} = 2^{32}$$ possible strings of length $32.$

Indeed, in creating a string of length $n$, there are $2^n$ possible such strings.

Comment: so if it asked How many binary bit strings of length 1692 are there? it would just be $2^{1692}$

Comment: Yes, that's correct.